# Changing default permissions on a new windows file moved into the WSL directory tree. How?

Tags: file-permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I often use file explorer to move/copy a windows file into the WSL environment for bash manipulation.  All the windows files I move/copy in this way have permissions set to 000 by default. I have to use chmod to turn the permissions back on.

Is there some default I can set in WSL to have the correct permissions on the file without using chmod?  umask seems useless, since the file was not created in WSL.

I am using WSL 1.

Comment: What path are you using to access your WSL1 distribution in Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

The default permissions are set on a per-distribution basis in the file
`wsl.conf`, and globally for all WSL 2 distributions in `.wslconfig`.

From  [File Permissions for WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions):

> You can configure your file permissions inside of your Windows drives using the mount options in `wsl.conf`. The mount options allow you to set `umask`, `dmask` and `fmask` permissions masks. The `umask` is applied to all files, the `dmask` is applied just to directories and the `fmask` is applied just to files. These permission masks are then put through a logical OR operation when being applied to files, e.g: If you have a `umask` value of 023 and an `fmask` value of 022 then the resulting permissions mask for files will be 023.

In addition, the article
[Advanced settings configuration in WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#per-distribution-configuration-options-with-wslconf)
describes what is happening in your case:

[image]

An example of an `/etc/wsl.conf` in your WSL distribution:

```
[automount]
options="metadata,case=dir,umask=22,fmask=111"
```

More information can be found by searching. For example
[Fix WSL File System Behavior](https://akr.am/blog/posts/fix-wsl-file-system-behavior),
but there are many more.

Comment: *Probably* not relevant in this case.  The OP is going *from* a Windows drive *to* WSL1.  For this to be part of the problem, they would already have had to *set* the `metadata` option as well as a mask that would result in an empty permissions set.  That would be pathologic or highly unlikely to do by mistake.